# How do you open a tsv file in jupyter?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, jupyter-notebook

this is my code and it isn't working, I have the file saved as shet_v2.txt
::

```
import pandas as pd
import os

working_directory = os.getcwd()
print(working_directory)

path = working_directory + '/data/shet_v2.txt'
shet = pd.read_csv(path, sep='\t')
```

and this is the error message that pops up and i'm not sure how to fix it
::

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> '/Users/jasonlee/Desktop/data/shet_v2'

Comment: I assume the error includes the file suffix i.e. shet_v2.txt rather than just shet_v2.  Anyway, Python is not finding the file.  You should check if the file is actually in the folder.

Comment: Try replacing '/' with '\' in the path.

Answer (score 1):

If you're opening .tsv file from your local, please attempt the below code:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.csv_read(r'c:\User\anna\train.tsv', sep='\t')

print(df)
```